# C# Decode base64 Zlib string with Ionic.Zlib

Tags: c#, mono, base64, zlib, ionic-framework

I'm trying to decode a compressed string inside an XML without any success:
Basically I want to decode and get back the decoded string.

This is the xml node with my compressed data:

```
<data encoding="base64" compression="zlib">
   eJztmNkKwjAQRaN9cAPrAq5Yq3Xf6vVIbQJjEZR+nDwQZScrwztoORECLySBcIgZ7nc2y4KfyWDLx+Jb9nViNgDEwY+KioAXUgQN4+zpoCMwPmQAtoAx2CLFbA2oDEo9+hwG8DnIDtF/2K8ks086Tw2zH0uyMv7HcRr/6/EvvhnsPrsrxwX7rwU/0ODig/eV3mh3N1ld8eraWPaX6+64s9McesfrqcHfg1MpoifxcVEWjukyw+9AtFPl/I71pER3Of6j4bv7HI54s+MChhqLlPdZ/P3qMmFuo5h5NnTOhjM5tReN2yT51n5/v7J3F0vi46fk+ne7aX0i9l6If7mpufTX3f5wsqv9TAD2fJLT9VrTn7UeZnM5tR+v0LMQOHXwFnxe2/warGFRWf8QDjOLfP
  </data>
```

Because of Unity and Mono (the env I'm working on) I can't use System.IO.Compression. 
so that I'm implementing Ionic.Zlib.

This is the syntax:

```
public static string DecodeBase64Gzip(string input) 
{       
  byte[ ] ZlibBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
  MemoryStream comp = new MemoryStream(ZlibBuffer);
  Stream zlib = new Ionic.Zlib.ZlibStream (comp, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress);
  return new System.IO.StreamReader (zlib, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
}
```

For sure I'm doing some mistake because as output i get an empty string.

I tryied also in that way:

```
public static string DecodeBase64Zlib(string input)
    {
        byte[ ] ZlibBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
        return ZlibStream.UncompressString (ZlibBuffer);
}
```

But with the same result (empty string...)

Have you some advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

"This is the xml node with my compressed data".  How did you compress the data?  It is messed up somehow.  After base64 decoding (which by the way does not terminate properly), the data starts with a valid zlib header, but that is followed by invalid deflate data.

Comment: Hi Mark. The tmx (xml!) file is compressed from another software, following these rules: https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format#data  As I told before the compression is done with zlib and the encoding is base64. I don't get any header or other exception.

Comment: I don't know how, but the data you provided is not what is described.  The zlib stream is corrupted, and the base64 string is not complete.  You should verify that you are extracting the data correctly, and that there is no error in your cut and paste into the question.